# how to serve .net console on Nginx?

Tags: c#, .net, nginx

So I got it to the stage where the .net (framework) console application could run on localhost, but the next issue is exposing it using Nginx.

I looked at many tutorials, but they all seems to be for websites. How can i make it work for a console app?

Thank you.

---

> What do you gain from using nginx in front of it instead of just
> opening the console app on port 80 (or preferably 443 witha
> certificate)? You will probably need to set up nginx as a reverse
> proxy for your app.

I have the console app running on port 1234 because there is already an app using port 80. To be honest, I am not sure why I am using Nginx, I just assume that's what I need, since I have the app running on localhost but I cannot access it from outside. I have set the firewall to accept that port from the domain provider side.

> uhm.... what exactly do you mean by "exposing a console application"?
> because what you expose with nginx - or any other webserver - is a
> website. also: welcome to stackoverflow. i recommend taking the tour,
> as well as reading how to ask a good question and what's on topic.

Thank you. I am probably not using the most accurate term. Basically, I just want people to be able to access my app. In my mind, I imaging there is some additional setting I need to do to have it "exposed" to the public (and that's using nginx). I can see the app running on localhost but not sure why it's not public.

> please say what you expect a console app 'exposed to the public' would
> look like. How would they access it? What tool on my desktop would I
> start, ignore the nginx part of the discussion

So I have a loop serving some web content similar to this one.

https://gist.github.com/define-private-public/d05bc52dd0bed1c4699d49e2737e80e7

When I run it, external user should go to a website and see the page content served up by this.

> If your console app is a Console.ReadLine() Console.WriteLine() type
> thing the only way to expose it simply is to setup and SSH server on
> your host system. Then the users need an SSH client to access it. This
> is doable via web browser hosted SSH access but thats v complex
> solution

You can ignore all the Console Readline and Writeline stuff.

Comment: What do you gain from using nginx in front of it instead of just opening the console app on port 80 (or preferably 443 witha certificate)? You will probably need to set up nginx as a reverse proxy for your app.

Comment: uhm.... what exactly do you mean by "exposing a console application"? because what you expose with nginx - or any other _webserver_ - *is* a website. also: welcome to stackoverflow. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: please say what you expect a console app 'exposed to the public' would look like. How would they access it? What tool on my desktop would I start, ignore the nginx part of the discussion.

Comment: If your console app is a `Console.ReadLine()` `Console.WriteLine()` type thing the only way to expose it simply is to setup and SSH server on your host system. Then the users need an SSH client to access it. This is doable via web browser hosted SSH access but thats v complex solution

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the solution is actually quite simple. All you need to do is forward your incoming request to a localhost using proxy_pass, as suggested by @fredrik. The following should be added to the default config file (under nginx):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8888/;
    }
}
```